# What events, tests, and troubles could a party trying to establish a nation expect to face

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, homebrew, roleplaying, world-building

My players have decided to establish a new nation which consists of Phandalin, Triboar, Red Larch, and all lands in between (per their own highly unofficial declaration).  I'm trying to come up with some things to present these new kings and queens that will test their abilities to govern well.  Are there any resources that could help me with creating rules / balance to their nation building?

A few details that might help:

- The party is level 12
- They are a generally chaotic good party consisting of a Rogue,
  Sorcerer, Druid/Ranger, and Rogue/Warlock
- The campaign started with Lost Mines of Phandelver and transitioned
  into a slightly homebrewed version of Princes of the Apocalypse

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be "idea generation" or a "list" question, with no one "best" answer likely to appear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is idea generation

Comment: Wouldn't those both be "too broad" instead of "off topic"? Either way, this question isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange. A [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449) will be a better help. Also, [Matt Colville does a good video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYlLTtS-tfQ) on this sort of thing popping up in tabletop RPGs.

Comment: Thank you sevenbrokenbricks.  I looked into the Matt Colville videos and they were very good at inspiring some political intrigue that I can use in my campaign.  Very much appreciate it!

Comment: I’m running a game of my own in which the party helping found a province like this is the campaign’s inciting incident. I don’t know how to do direct messages on SE, otherwise I’d offer that!

Comment: @sevenbrokenbricks: SE doesn't have any direct-message functionality. That said, Mr.Levistus has more than enough reputation to join the [chat], so you could discuss this there. (Though Mr.Levistus doesn't have enough reputation to create a chat room himself, you could make one if you wish.)